# How to interpret the Dapr sidecar performance tests?

Tags: performance, testing, microservices, sidecar, dapr

If I understand correctly, the [Dapr docs](https://docs.dapr.io/operations/performance-and-scalability/perf-service-invocation/#data-plane-performance) say that a single sidecar uses 0.48 vCPU under the specified conditions.

Does this mean that if a huge app like Netflix or Uber (which use more than a thousand microservices) is going to use Dapr then it will need more than 480 vCPU? It's scary.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to interpret or extrapolate a percentage of overall CPU from that test report. It says...

> The Dapr sidecar uses 0.48 vCPU and 23Mb per 1000 requests per second.

Strictly speaking they are just saying that at a thoughtput rate of 1000 requests/sec via the dapr sidecar, 0.48 vCPU is consumed. The Dapr service generating that test load might have been idling on async await statements for responses or it could have been consuming 8.0 vCPUs.